# how can i create AVD in android 4.4W.2?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new to android. I've installed eclipse (API20) with java 8. Problem is i cant create AVD. I tried many combinations but it does not work. Whats the right way of getting AVD?

Comment: what kind of problem you are facing ? is ok button disable ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific when you say "doesn't work" (some output log).

Go to Windows > Android Virtual Device Manager

[image]
[image]

Fill required fields and create device.